# CodeMirror: auto-resize horizontally, without scrollbar

Tags: codemirror

I need a CodeMirror editor which starts with a certain width and then grows automatically to the right to match the maximum line length. I.e. roughly what CodeMirror does [when `height` is set to `auto`](https://codemirror.net/demo/resize.html), but with width.

Here's a [self-contained example](http://jsbin.com/hojibehedi/1/edit?html,output). The editor grows automatically along the y-axis fine, but not along the x-axis. By tweaking the CSS, I can either have a fixed width editor with a scrollbar, or one which fills the entire width of the browser, but not one which grows as you type. I assume `overflow-x` is relevant, but I don't understand how it interacts with other CSS size properties set on parent elements. I also tried setting that property on `CodeMirror-scroll`, but it didn't help.

I believe this can be done using CSS properties alone. In fact I have this behaviour in my application already, but growing to the left, rather than the right, but I don't understand why it happens, or how to reproduce it in a small example.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330326/codemirror-disabling-vertical-scroll-bar) is essentially the same, but for the vertical scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `float:left` to the CodeMirror `div`.

```
<div id="here" style="float:left"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not something CodeMirror supports. You may be able to get something working by setting `.CodeMirror`'s `width` to (`-webkit-`)`fit-content`, but there will likely be corner cases where this breaks the scrollbars or cursor placement.